# ansible: get macaddress of connection_name: "Ethernet" (Windows Host)

Tags: windows, ansible, jinja2, ansible-facts

I would like to rename a Windows Host by mac address.
I have a csv file with MAC;HOSTNAME.

I am at the step to get the macaddress of the connection named "Ethernet".

when i do ansible -m setup [...] i get the following:

```
        "ansible_interfaces": [
        {
            "connection_name": "Ethernet",
            "default_gateway": "192.168.92.1",
            "dns_domain": null,
            "interface_index": 12,
            "interface_name": "Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (6) I219-LM",
            "macaddress": "A4:AE:11:1C:D5:7F"
        },
        {
            "connection_name": "WLAN",
            "default_gateway": null,
            "dns_domain": null,
            "interface_index": 18,
            "interface_name": "Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz",
            "macaddress": "8C:C6:81:63:34:45"
        },
        {
            "connection_name": "LAN-Verbindung* 1",
            "default_gateway": null,
            "dns_domain": null,
            "interface_index": 15,
            "interface_name": "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter",
            "macaddress": "8C:C6:81:63:34:46"
        },
        {
            "connection_name": "LAN-Verbindung* 10",
            "default_gateway": null,
            "dns_domain": null,
            "interface_index": 9,
            "interface_name": "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2",
            "macaddress": "8E:C6:81:63:34:45"
        },
        {
            "connection_name": "Bluetooth-Netzwerkverbindung",
            "default_gateway": null,
            "dns_domain": null,
            "interface_index": 10,
            "interface_name": "Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)",
            "macaddress": "8C:C6:81:63:34:49"
        }
```

**How can i put the "maccaddress" of the correct interface in a variable?**
Is this a dict or an array?

Comment: Can you try with `ansible_interfaces[0].macaddress`?

Comment: hmm... i reject the reality that i am pretty sure i tried it before, but...
your suggestion is correct and works like intended. Thank you @Marko-e

Answer (score 1):

as @Marko E suggested the solution is that easy:

```
{{ ansible_interfaces[0].macaddress }}
```

just did the trick.

Maybe some can come up with a "connection_name is $STRING" solution?
But the above did the trick for me now.